# NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER in sandbox account paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have integrated paypal-adaptive-payment-delayed-chained-payments in my Rails Application and there will Primary receiver hold whole amount and sender can cancel the product and refund the amount.

I am using paypal `sandbox` account for testing but getting `"refund_status"=>"NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER"` this after call refund and `paypal success is true`
so I am confusing what that mean, as I know in sandbox paypal provide full access

log is:

{"response_envelope"=>{"timestamp"=>"2015-10-06T22:55:49.604-07:00", "ack"=>"Success", "correlation_id"=>"9f0f563554297", "build"=>"17820627"}, "currency_code"=>"USD", "refund_info_list"=>{"refund_info"=>[{"receiver"=>{"amount"=>"60.00", "email"=>"test@gmail.com"}, "refund_status"=>"NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER"}]}}

Please let me know where I am doing wrong

Comment: How did you do it? I am having trouble implementing delayed payment. Please help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508038/how-to-make-a-delayed-payment-with-pp-adaptive-gem-in-rails

Comment: Can you please explain what is the solution. I facing same problem. and i have also add third party permission. I am confused which name will be added in third party permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status `NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER` indicates that the request cannot be completed because you do not have third-party access from the receiver to make the refund.

Sandbox account has provided full access but when it comes to Adaptive Payments (Chained) Refund in particular, you would need your refund API caller (in your case, the primary receiver) to be granted with refund permission (3rd party access to make a refund on-behalf) from all secondary recievers in the chain.

Check [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) (the **Refund API Overview** section) for instructions

Comment: Can you please explain what is the solution. I facing same problem. and i have also  add third party permission. I am confused which name will be added in third party permission.